# Warning with settingsWithCopyWarning , when creating another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data as shown here:

```
    SampleNumber    X  A  B
0              1  120  2  4
1              2  120  2  4
2              3  120  2  4
3              4  120  2  4
4              5  120  2  4
5              6  120  2  4
6              7    0  2  4
7              8    0  2  4
8              9    0  2  4
9             10    0  2  4
10            11    0  2  4
11            12    0  2  4
12            13    0  2  4
13            14  150  2  4
14            15  150  2  4
15            16    0  2  4
16            17    0  2  4
17            18  135  2  4
18            19  135  2  4
19            20    0  2  4
20            21    0  2  4
```

I have a column X where most of the values of the same and values sometimes changes
I need data when the values in column X changes and it is not 0.

**Output:**
I need samples: 1, 14,18
The way I am doing is

```
common_t_filtered_df['C'] = common_t_filtered_df['X'].diff()
df_filtered = common_t_filtered_df[common_t_filtered_df['C']!=0]
try:
   df_filtered = df_filtered[df_filtered['X'] != 0]
   df_filtered = (df_filtered[['A','B','X','SampleNumber']]).values
```

I keep getting this error:

> line:err: SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a
> copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using
> .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> common_t_filtered_df['C'] = common_t_filtered_df['X'].diff()

Can someone let me know how can I get rid of this error or maybe there is some smart idea of getting the values. Btw 120,150,135 are just examples, it can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `pandas` incorrectly. In this case, I'm not going to fully address the question of why you are getting this particular error as that is all over the internet. However, as a short answer, you can often avoid this error my creating a `copy()` of the dataframe prior to slicing it (e.g. `df1 = df.copy()`). But, I would suggest you just use the following code instead of using `try` statements.

You just have to filter your dataframe for conditions that meet the conditions you have set. You are looking for `shift()` and when the value is not equal to 0 with `ne(0)`:

```
df = df[df['X'].ne(0) & df['X'].ne(df['X'].shift())]

Out[1]: 
    SampleNumber    X  A  B
0              1  120  2  4
13            14  150  2  4
17            18  135  2  4
```

To get just `SampleNumber`, use:

```
df['SampleNumber'].tolist()

Out[2]:
[1, 14, 18]
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction